# Proof: Given that $x$ is a positive integer, prove...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

**Given that x is a positive integer, prove that $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ will never be divisible by $5$.**

I've tried a contrapostive proof so far:
Assume $f(x)$ is divisible by $5$. Then, $x^2 + x + 1 = 5p$ for some integer $p$.

$x(x+1) + 1 = 5p$

Since $x(x+1)$ has to be even because an even number times an odd number if even, $x(x+1)$ is odd. Thus, p is odd (the product of 5 and an odd number is an odd number). Thus:

$x(x+1) + 1 = 5(2n+1)$ for some integer $n$.

$x^2 + x - (10n+4) = 0$.

I need to show that x is NOT an integer, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Hint: is $(x-5)$ a factor of the polynomial? How does that help us?

Comment: You can try with induction.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=x^2 + x+1$ will never be divisible by five?

Comment: In this type of questions I used to work as follows: $\mathbb{N}$ can be splitted into sets of the form $\{5k\}, \{5k+1\}, \{5k+2\}, \{5k+3\}, \{5k+4\}$ replacing case by case in your formula, it-s easy to check that no one of them has remainder 0.

Comment: Hint: is (x−5) a factor of the polynomial? How does that help us? (Sorry for posting this as an answer earlier, btw)

Comment: @RanjeevGrewal How do you suggest to "see" that $x-5$ is, or is not, a factor of $x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z[x]$? Of course it is not a factor in $\mathbb Z[x]$ or in $\mathbb C[x]$, but this says nothing about the present question.

Answer (score 1):

Check $$0^2+0+1\not\equiv0,$$

$$1^2+1+1\not\equiv0,$$

$$2^2+2+1\not\equiv0,$$

$$3^2+3+1\not\equiv0$$ and

$$4^2+4+1\not\equiv0.$$